# Animation hides the image android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

i used below single line code for animation to my image view in android.

Coding

```
        v.animate().translationXBy(1000).setDuration(5000).start();
```

but i hides the image. i don't want to hide my image using the above source. any helps are much welcome thanks.

Comment: what is the width (in pixels) of your device?

Comment: use v.animate().translationXBy(100).setDuration(5000).start(); as translationXBy is number by wghich you translate

Comment: my question is i want move the image not hide using single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
v.bringToFront();
```

Add this before animating.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

how do you want to hide your image?

you can also hide it by set 0 in alpha attribute

```
v.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500).start();
```

**EDIT**

To move the view right to left without hide it at the end

You can try to use v.animate.x() instead

1. Set the min X Position, its 0 since you want to move it to left without goes out of screen

> int minXPosition = 0;

2. Set the value how much the view move and calculate the view new X position

> int moveXBy = 100;
>
> int newXPosition = (int)view.getX()-moveXBy;

3. Animate the view, but check the position first -> if its past your minXPosition, use the minXPosition instead

> `view.animate()
>   .x(newXPosition<minXPosition?minXPosition:newXPosition)
>   .setDuration(500)
>   .start();`

Comment: i want to move my icon from right to left. i don't want o hide the image. but  the above mentioned code by my will move form right to left and hiding. can you refine it.

Comment: mm, so you want moving the view to left / right but without make it hidden at the end?